# WCF service not working when a System.Windows.Control is created inside the service implementation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf

I have a WCF service with a service contract (let's call it IHelloWorldService). Inside the contract implementation (don't ask why...) the constructor creates a System.Windows.Control instance.

Well, with this configuration, the service does not work at all. It seems to start perfectly but when I make a request to the service (even when I ask for the metadata in the browser) the service does not respond.
The funny thing is that if I create the System.Windows.Form in another thread (just inside a task for example), the service works perfectly. The service is a singleton, so, it is not creating new instances per call. The control is created once.

A quick pseudocode of my example would be:

The service host creation:

```
   ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(new HelloWorldService(), "callback");
```

The service:

```
   class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
   {
       public HelloWorldService() : this(new System.Windows.Control())
       {}

       public HelloWorldService(System.Windows.Control control){}
   }
```

The previous example does not work. However, if I create the HelloWorldService in another thread, for example, in a Task, it works perfectly.
The quick crude pseudocode example:

```
   ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(CreateHelloWorldService(), "callback");

   HelloWorldService CreateHelloWorldService()
   {
       HelloWorldService service;
       Task newTask = new Task{ service = new HelloWorldService() };
       newTask.Run().Wait();
       return service;
   }
```

This example works well. My guess is that maybe the main thread suffers some kind of change when the it creates the control and then the WCF stack is not able to process the request. This problem is the simplification of a bigger one and, although I'm able to solve it with the thread thing, I would like/need to understand what is going on and why is not working properly in order to explain the big issue in the real environment program.

Apologies for my English. In case something is not clear, please, let me know and I will try to clarify it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are making a form in a service?

Comment: I love the "don't ask why" part. I'm not judging. Really. But something tells me that the "why" has to be one of the most awesome stories I've never heard. How can we not ask why? Please, I have to know.

Comment: I'm dealing with a legacy code which is a pain in the ass. The service acts as a controller for a sound card. This sound card is managed by directX and Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.Device.SetCooperativeLevel receives as a param a System.Windows.Form ... This is all I know. This piece of software is "deprecated" but a legacy project is facing an issue... I discovered this thing that could explain what is going on but I don't even know whether this could cause the error or not. I'm just trying to understand the problem... Long story but not intereseting, that's the reason of the "don't ask" xD

Answer (score 0):

1. A service is not meant to create a Windows forms component. Even if you succeed in achieving the creation somehow, there will be issues interacting with it later on.
2. Windows form controls are meant to be handled in a background thread, as the thread creating it must be same as the thread interacting with it. All interactions will need to use InvokeRequired and then do BeginInvoke in the pre-TPL time. With TPL, using interaction should be in Task bounded operation
3. In your code snippet, since the actual thread being used gets disposed after the method call, the form will become a zombie since there will be no reference to control it.. (an example of possible future problems with handling forms in service)

Code wise, as long as we are using Invoke/BeginInvoke, there's NO issue, as illustrated in sample below

```
public delegate void myDel();

public class Service1 : MyService
{
    private WindowsFormsApp1.Form1 form;

    public Service1()
    {
        this.form = new WindowsFormsApp1.Form1();
    }

    private void SetFormData()
    {
        this.form.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 500);
    }
    public void DoSomeFun()
    {
        this.form.Show();
        myDel del = new myDel(SetFormData);
        this.form.Invoke(del);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

1. Yes, I know a service is not meant to host a form. The real development is a SoundPlayerController which is hosted in the service. This SoundPlayerController uses a DirectX device which needs a form in order to set the cooperative level. Maybe it could be done in a better way, but this is a legacy code that I can't change.

2. I don't know if this affects my scenario. If I understood you, my scenario should work then I create the form in the same thread and fail when I use a new one..

3. Yes, my code snippet is a simplification just to give you and idea.

Comment: how about a separate application which can call a service method?

Comment: Not possible. We can't make any relevant change. We have a software in production and sometimes (we are not able to reproduce it in dev environment) after restart the service the endpoints are not reacheable.
Digging in the code I found this rare thing about the control inside the service. This is done inside a separate thread (this is why it works). I put it in the main thread and I observe that the endpoints are not reacheable. I don't even know whether this is related to the real bug, this is why I'm trying to undertand what is really happening.
I really appreciatte your help! Thank you!

Comment: @MiguelAngelRodriguez added a sample code for WCF setting a Form in constructor and then accessing it in service methods.. It works fine, maybe there's something else being done with the form (like ignoring BeginInvoke) which leads to exception, and the service being a singleton, dies..

Comment: Yes, this could explain the real scenario problem because I don't really know how this form is used inside the DirectX library... but in my simple example, the form is only stored in a field inside the service implementation. I debugged the request from the wcf stack. It started the process but in some place (which I'm not able to found) the process stucks. Sorry, I'm feeling that I'm making lose your time but I can't give you more information. With your code, is it working without doing anything with the form? Thanks again!!

Comment: yes, my form is entirely empty, and it just goes away once the service request is complete.. Was an interesting check so tried to sample it actually to go beyond concepts